# Crop image height in PHP

Tags: php

Hello I would like to know how I can change the $ny variable to crop the image to 240 pixes.The crop should be realized from top and bottom. Here is my code so far:

```
 $final_width_of_thumb = 180;  
 $nx = $final_width_of_thumb;  
 $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_big / $ox)); 

 $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);  

 imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);
 imagejpeg($nm, $folder_thumb . $final_file);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `imagecrop()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you to crop. You need PHP 5.5.0 or greater to use this code.

```
<?php
    $link='image.jpg';
    $height_crop=240;
    $image=imagecreatefromjpeg($link);
    $size_array=getimagesize($link);
    $width=$size_array[0];
    $height=$size_array[1];
    $es_height=($height-$height_crop)/2;
    $im_dimension=array('x'=>0,'y'=>$es_height,'width'=>$width,'height'=>240);
    $croped=imagecrop($image,$im_dimension);
    imagejpeg($croped,'new.jpeg',80);
```